# Prisma is console.logging things out of my control

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have a project that is using postgreSQL and Prisma. I was console.logging something in getServerSideProps(), but I noticed that is prisma is automatically console.logging huge amounts of strings like `prisma:query SELECT "public"."TaskChart"."id", "public"."TaskChart"."name", "public"."TaskChart"."dateCreated", "public"."TaskChart"."default", "public"."TaskChart"."owner" FROM "public"."TaskChart" WHERE "public"."TaskChart"."owner" = $1 OFFSET $2 /* traceparent=00-00-00-00 */` How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Try handling your `prisma` errors with this code :

```js
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const client = new PrismaClient()

try {
  await client.user.create({ data: { email: 'alreadyexisting@mail.com' } })
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
    // The .code property can be accessed in a type-safe manner
    if (e.code === 'P2002') {
      console.log(
        'There is a unique constraint violation, a new user cannot be created with this email'
      )
    }
  }
  throw e
```

Also check [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference) reference

Answer (score 1):

Try checking your prisma instance.
If it is like this:

```
export const prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log:
      env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? ["query", "error", "warn"] : ["error"],
  });
```

Then, remove `log:` from options.

```
export const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```